# How to solve $-\Delta f(x,y) = 1, \ \ (x,y) \in (0,1)^2$, $f(x,y)=1, \ \ (x,y) \in \partial (0,1)^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

### Problem

> Solve : $-\Delta f(x,y) = 1, \ \ (x,y) \in (0,1)^2$, $f(x,y)=1, \ \ (x,y) \in \partial (0,1)^2$

---

### Try

I'm not familiar with the problem, so just spreading the formula out,

$$
- \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(x,y) - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} u(x,y) = 1
$$

but I do not have any ideas on the Ansatz of the solution. Any help?